# Homology and retraction

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

I have a problem with some short exact sequence in homology:

Let $A\subset X$, $i: A\hookrightarrow X$, $j: X\hookrightarrow (X,A)$ be an inclusions and $r: X\rightarrow A$ be a retraction. 
Since $r\circ i=id_{A}$, we get that $H(r)\circ H(i)=id_{H(A)}$ and hence $H(i)$ is monomorphism, and $H(r)$ is epimorphism.

Now I should get a short exact sequence in homology:
$$0\rightarrow H_q(A)\xrightarrow{H(i)} H_q(X)\xrightarrow{H(j)} H_q(X,A)\rightarrow 0.$$

And my question is how do we get this?
Firstly, in long exact sequence we get the connecting homomorphism 
$$\ldots \rightarrow H_q(X,A)\xrightarrow{\partial_*} H_{q-1}(A)\xrightarrow{H(i)} H_{q-1}(X)$$ but since $H(i)$ is mono, why is not any term $H_*(X,A)=0$?

How retraction implies it? I understand that thanks to composition $r\circ i$ we have $H(i)$-mono, and $j$ should induce a zero homomorphism in homology, but, again, then $H(X,A)$ would be equal to $0$.

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: $H(i)$ mono $\Leftrightarrow \ker H(i)=0 \Leftrightarrow \operatorname{Im}\partial_*=0\Leftrightarrow \partial_*=0$. Only the map $\partial_*$ is zero, not necessarily the module $H(X,A)$ nor the map $H(j)$. Note also that, because $\partial_*=0$, you can cut the long exact sequence to get the desired short exact sequences.

Comment: Ok, but why in this case doesn't work the property that $0\rightarrow A\xrightarrow{i} B$ is exact if and only if $i$ is a monomorphism?

Comment: I don't see any contradiction with what I said. What you wrote **DOES NOT** mean that given an exact sequence $N\rightarrow A\overset{i}\rightarrow B$, then $i$ monomorphism iff $N=0$.